# Residue question on contour integral

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm asked to evaluate the following contour integral $$\int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{(z^4+1)(z-3)}$$ where $\gamma$ is the circle of radius $2$ centered at the origin and travelled once in the counterclockwise direction.

My approach: I know how to calculate the integral but my question is, do I have to include all of the 4 singularities of $z^4+1=0$?  or just one of them, say, $e^{i \pi/4}$? Or more clearly, is this integral equal to $$2 \pi i*(Res(f,3)+Res(f,e^{i \pi/4})+Res(f,e^{i3 \pi/4}) +Res(f,e^{i5 \pi/4})+Res(f,e^{i7 \pi/4}))$$ and of course, the residue at $z=3$ is zero.

Comment: Yes, you need to calculate residues on all singularities that contour covers.

Comment: The residue at 3 isn't zero, it is outside the contour that interests you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to take into account all four singularities of $z^4 + 1$; (note also that the residues aren't equal at different poles). Perhaps it's more obvious if you write the integral as

$$\int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{(z - e^{i\pi/4})(z - e^{3i\pi/4})(z - e^{5i\pi/4})(z - e^{7i\pi/4})(z - 3)} dz $$

---

Also, the residue of $f$ at $z = 3$ is *not* zero; rather, we don't include that singularity in the sum since it doesn't lie within the contour $\gamma$.

Comment: Yes pardon me. I meant to say the index is zero.

Comment: Did u mean to put a $e^{i7 \pi/4}$ on one of your factors?

Comment: This is such a tedious integral to compute

Comment: Geez I think I am having difficulty computing this integral. The arithmetic is amazing. I get something very funny